# jQuery open / close divs based on selected item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a small application that people can edit specific areas on the page (like a small CMS)

I have following HTML

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="zone">
     <div class="editor">
       <ul>
        <li>Bold</li>
        <li>Italic</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="content">Some Content</div>
   </div>

   <div class="zone">
     <div class="editor">
       <ul>
        <li>Bold</li>
        <li>Italic</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="content">Some More Content</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

What I'm looking to do, is if i click on a zone then the `editor` div is shown for the particular `zone`. All others must then close (since I'm not editing the zone)

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery().find('div.editor').hide();
  jQuery(".main").selectable({
         filter: 'div:not(.content)'
  });

    jQuery(".zone").each(function() {

      jQuery(this).find(".content").click(function(e) { 
        var parent = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

        var selected = parent.find('div.zone.ui-selected');

        selected.find('div.editor').show();

      });

    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: So is it the "all others must then close" part that you're stuck on, or...?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Each time I click on the `zone` div, the `editor` div opens. So with the example above, I have 2 `editor` divs open, whilst I only need the editor to open based on which `zone` I'm editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hide() function is only executed once - on domready after the page loaded.

you have to move your hide-code inside your click function

```
 jQuery(this).find(".content").click(function(e) {
    jQuery().find('div.editor').hide();
    var parent = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

    var selected = parent.find('div.zone.ui-selected');
```

E: As mentioned you have to add the hide() inside your click event.

```
$('div.editor').hide();
```

Also you shouldn't use js to initially hide content. Use CSS display:none to prevent some show/hide on pageload. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aAvC5/4/

Comment: That hasn't affected the way it works currently. When I click on any of the `zone` divs, they always stay open.

Comment: yes because you never define a hide() anywhere. after you click you have to select all open zone's, hide them and make sure the selectable is set correctly. please put you're code into a jsfiddle.net and I will help you further

Comment: check my edit. simply hide all editors on click and you're done.